# How to add a back button to action bar / toolbar

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, back

I have written a piece of code as part of an app where I want to implement a back button on the action bar/tool bar such that when the button is pressed, the previous page (the page/fragment immediately before the current page/fragment) will be displayed.

This is the code for the ToolBar, DrawerLayout, NavigationView and getSupportActionBar():

```
final DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
final NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar toolbar = (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
toolbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

I am unable to use ActionBar. For some reason (I don't know why), my Android studio/ program, will not allow me to use the ActionBar. So I am substituting that with the set/getSupportActionBar().

The function used in relation to this are:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
     MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
     inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_settings, menu);
     return true;
}        

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

     // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
     // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
     // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

     int id = item.getItemId();

     switch (id) {
         case android.R.id.home:
             onBackPressed();
             return true;
         default:
             return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
         }
    }        

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();        
    }
}
```

My activity_main.xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:openDrawer="start"
    tools:context="com.example.albin.settings_menu.SettingsActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#fff">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:title="Settings"/>

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar">

        </FrameLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/nav_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="-24dp"
                app:menu="@menu/options_menu" />


        </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

The problem is that I don't know which is the useful code, which is the useless code and how to mix/join/(add additional codes to) these (codes, methods, variables/objects, fragments, xml layouts) to get the desired outcome, that is, the application of a back button on the action bar/tool bar.

Most of the code above is implemented for the up button, not the back button. I have read at several places that up and back buttons are not the same.

I tried several links on internet as well as on this site, but none of them has just what I need.

Hope someone can give me an  clear answer...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can include the back icon in `ToolBar`:

Initialize `ToolBar`:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

- You can use an `drawable` icon as a back button.

  ```
  toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.your_drawable_icon);

  toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
          // what do you want here
      }
  });
  ```
- If you do not want to use `drawable` icon then:

  ```
  getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
  getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

  toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
          // what do you want here
      }
  });
  ```

Comment: What happens if you have more than one view in the support action bar and that icon is clicked? I think you need to specify the views that are clicked in onClick method

Answer (score 2):

Actually your layout having that issue because you have added toolbar in `RelativeLayout` so drawer layout is overlapping on it that's why you would not able to click on back arrow, i have fix your layout see below

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_back_black"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:title="Settings" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar" />

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:menu="@menu/options_menu" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to add parent activity in manifest file as developer docs suggest.

```
 <activity 
    android:name=".ChildActivity"
    android:parentActivityName=".ParentActivity" >
```

and java code you already have done it, setSupportActionbar and setHomeAsUpEnabled.

Edited : 
its necessary to add up action for icon to be visible, as mentioned in 
[Android Developer Docs](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html)

Comment: This is not true, at least if you are using CollapsingToolbarLayout.
Adding android: parentActivityName = "activityParentName" in the manifest does not show the arrow back button, however if you add getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);   appears

Comment: @EmmanuelGuther thanks for information,your correct i have edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

So toolbar gives added flexibility to modify title-bar in Android.

As far as why `getActionBar` is not working and you are compelled to use `getSupportActionBar` is because you must be using `SupportLibrary`. SupportLibrary gives backward compatibility to earlier SDK versions.

> If you want to modify your title-bar/header/action-bar extensively
>   then use toolbar otherwise use action-bar.

Answer (score 0):

Add a navigation click listener to your toolbar , like below

```
toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onBackPressed();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are referencing some actions from the action bar, such as a Save action or a Share one, and you are overriding *onOptionsItemSelected* method, then you need to define the behavior when the *back* or *home* button is clicked:

```
@Override public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
      case R.id.action_save:
        //save stuff
      break;

      //this is what you need to add to reference again back/home button
      case android.R.id.home:
        //do your stuff here, usually back to the home or close the current activity
        getActivity().finish();
      break;

      default:
      break;
    }
    return true;
```